# Doing an iframe intelligent?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, iframe

The idea of the following code is that it  has an iframe (that's necessary because the application has this html structure). When the parent window body element has the class 'IntelligenceEnabled' the iframe activates to all the 'a' tagnames the action of an alert( "I'am intelligent!"); and when the class isn't present, the links on the iframe will be disabled automatically.

The problem is: the code works well, but sometimes when the user clicks 'showMessage' links in the iframe after a switch (disable/enable) these links redirects to the urls (facebook, yahoo, google...) and no shows the message. Or the contrary efect, the messages are showed ever.

What I'm doing wrong? (both are on the same domain iframe and parent window)

```
<html>
<script type="tex/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {

    $("body.IntelligenceEnabled #IamIntelligent").on( 'load', function() {
        $("body.IntelligenceEnabled #IamIntelligent").contents().delegate( '.showMessage', 'load', function() {
            alert("I'am intelligent");
            return false;
        });
     });

     $('#enableIntelligence').click( function() {
        $('body').addClass('IntelligenceEnabled');
        return false;
     });

     $('#disableIntelligence').click( function() {
        $('body').removeClass('IntelligenceEnabled');
        return false;
     });

});
</script>
<body>
<iframe id="IamIntelligent" src="/foo.html"></iframe>
<a href="#" id="enableIntelligence">Enable my intelligence!</a>
<a href="#" id="disableIntelligence">Make me gross!!!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

(/foo.html)

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="showMessage">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" class="showMessage">Facebook</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="showMessage">Yahoo</a>
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com" class="showMessage">Microsoft</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the parent frame were able to inspect content in the iframe, then imagine what would happen when you browse to "www.awesomesite.com" which embeds an iframe to www.yourbank.com that you have logged in on a different tab.

Answer (score 1):

U cannot delegate events to iframe contents on load like

`$("body.IntelligenceEnabled #IamIntelligent")`

this is not even executed.

Use the following code to get your functionaity.

```
$("#IamIntelligent").on( 'load', function() {
    $("#IamIntelligent").contents().delegate( '.showMessage', 'click', function(e) {
        if($(document.body).hasClass("IntelligenceEnabled")) {
            alert("I'am intelligent");
            return false;
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: yeah, this is the solution! but I have a doubt respect to that: for example when you write a rule in CSS like body.IntelligenceEnabled { background-color: red; } and body { background-color:white; } you know, the background will change automatically without use a IF (verification), what I'm trying is that: do like CSS. Maybe the question or idea is: How to do the code works only when the IntelligenceEnabled will present in the body class?.

Comment: Actualy in your case the `onload` function is not called when the page is loaded because `$("body.IntelligenceEnabled #IamIntelligent")` does not exist and after adding `.IntelligenceEnabled` the call is not made. CSS Selector engine works differently AFAIK.